# How can I call a method from another controller in a view without changing the current page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to I18N my website by allowing the user to set the locale from user preferences.

Following the instructions from this [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-a-locale), I have created a `switch_locale` method in `application_controller.rb`

```
around_action :switch_locale

def switch_locale(&action)
  locale = current_user.try(:locale) || I18n.default_locale
  I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
end
```

I would like to test this function by creating a link or a button that allows a user to select which locale they want. Is there a way to call this method from a view without changing the route?

Comment: You can't call controller methods directly from views. Because remember the view code all gets compiled to HTML and it's viewed in the user's browser. How could they call your Ruby method from there? All communication back to the server needs to be done via form submissions (or, for more advanced applications, Action Cable / websockets)

Comment: That being said, all controllers inherit from ApplicationController so this method can be called from any of the other controllers

Comment: Your `switch_locale` method work by evaluating `current_user.locale`. That means to render that current page in another locale you need to update the current_user's locale first. That means without changing how you handle locales you will need at least two requests to switch the locale: An update to the current user and then a redirect back to the page.